# How to check how long a Cassandra table has not been visited

Tags: cassandra-2.0

How to check how long a Cassandra table has not been visited, help me decide whether to delete this table

Comment: @liu feifei Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule of thumbs, post data and the attemps you've done to solve or answer your questions. Do not assume that the community will do the work for you.

Comment: Hi Serge. Sorry, I did not fully understand what you mean.

Comment: 啊。 对不起。 请你仔细阅读发贴的指示。基本规矩是你需要把数据和你自己尝试解决问题的程序码发上来。

Comment: @Serge de Gosson de Varennes  I understand what you mean, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No. Cassandra doesn't have any process that allows this. However, if you have a column containing a timestamp you may use the cqlsh to check when it was last updated:

```
select * from Table
limit 1
```

Other than that....no.